# SearchMonkey - exclude folders

Tags: search, searchmonkey

How to exclude folders from being search in SearchMonkey?

Can't see such a feature in neither `Advanced` nor `Options`.

[image]

Comment: You can't. It seems that no file search GUI utility for Linux allows this.